# How to Set the height of the parent row to be larger than its children in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Currently, I have tried to find the  way to set the parent row of treeview higher than its children due to I need to attached an image in each parent row

Currently, I tried to set the height in each parent row , by

Style.configure()

Anyway, seems no  effective

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.